# altair bar chart for grouped data sorting NOT working

Tags: charts, altair

[image]`Reservation_branch_code |   ON_ACCOUNT  | Rcount
:-------------------------------------------------:

0   1101               |      170     |      5484
1   1103               |      101     |    5111
2   1118               |       1      |    232
3   1121               |       0      |     27
4   1126               |       90     |    191`

would like to chart sorted by "Rcount"  and x axis is "Reservation_branch_code"

this below code gives me chart without Sorting by Rcount

```
base =alt.Chart(df1).transform_fold(
                                  ['Rcount', 'ON_ACCOUNT'],
                                  as_=['column', 'value']
                              )
bars = base.mark_bar().encode( 
                              
                             # x='Reservation_branch_code:N',
                             x='Reservation_branch_code:O',
                              y=alt.Y('value:Q', stack=None), # stack =None enables layered bar
                              color=alt.Color('column:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=["#f50520", "#bab6b7"])),  
                              tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['ON_ACCOUNT','Rcount']),
                             #order=alt.Order('value:Q')
                            
)
text = base.mark_text(                            
                                align='center',
                                color='black',
                                baseline='middle',
                                dx=0,dy=-8,  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
                                
                                ).encode( 
                                x='Reservation_branch_code:N',
                                y='value:Q', 
                                text=alt.Text('value:Q', format='.0f') 
                                )                        
rule = alt.Chart(df1).mark_rule(color='blue').encode(
                                y='mean(Rcount):Q'
                              )  

(bars+text+rule).properties(width=790,height=330)
```

i sorted data in dataframe...used in that df in  altair chart
but not found X axis is not sorted by Rcount column........Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a list with the sort order:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield):Q',
    y=alt.Y('site:N', sort=source['site'].unique().tolist())
)
```

[image]

Comment: Great Thanks...it is sorting....if possible can you please add one more variable in Y ...like in my above code  ['Rcount', 'ON_ACCOUNT']  with two colors.   also the mean line. Thank You