# Custom ordering in a grouped bar chart not applied in Altair?

Tags: altair

I am trying to achieve a custom sort order for a series of categories in [a grouped bar chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html).

An [issue on GitHub from a few years ago](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1826) suggests how to do this: by supplying a list with the custom `sort` order to [`alt.Column`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Column.html#altair.Column). Supplying a list with a sort answer is also mentioned in [Joel Ostblom's answer to this related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74696910/4647265).

Omitting the `sort` parameter from `alt.Column()` results in an alphabetical sorting:

[image: alphabetical ordering]

Supplying a custom sort order results in no ordering / equivalent to `sort=None` I think, since the columns appear in the same order as they appear in the data:

```py
sort=["easy to use", "easy to understand", "complete", "representative",
      "visually appealing", "b&l useful", "rating"]
```

[image: no ordering]

**Where am I going wrong in applying sort order?**

My data is shaped as follows:

```py
    timestamp           value   attribute   system
0   23/03/2024 16:28:33 4.0 representative  A
1   23/03/2024 16:28:33 5.0 representative  B
2   23/03/2024 16:28:33 4.0 representative  C
3   23/03/2024 16:28:33 3.0 easy to use A
4   23/03/2024 16:28:33 5.0 easy to use B
... ... ... ... ...
99  23/03/2024 19:24:41 5.0 b&l useful  B
100 23/03/2024 19:24:41 5.0 b&l useful  C
101 23/03/2024 19:24:41 3.0 rating  A
102 23/03/2024 19:24:41 5.0 rating  B
103 23/03/2024 19:24:41 5.0 rating  C
```

The attributes I am grouping by are:

```py
d1['attribute'].unique()
array(['representative', 'easy to use', 'easy to understand', 'complete',
       'visually appealing', 'b&l useful', 'rating'], dtype=object)
```

and I create the bar plot via:

```py
alt.Chart(d1).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('mean(value):Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1,5]),),
    alt.X('system:N', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-0, title=None,),),
    alt.Column(
        'attribute:N',
        sort=["easy to use", "easy to understand", "complete", "representative",
              "visually appealing", "b&l useful", "rating"],
        header=alt.Header(title=None, labelOrient='bottom'),
        
    ),
    color='system:N',
    tooltip=['mean(value)', 'attribute', 'system'],
)
```

Comment: **Note**: I am open to re-shaping my data if that would make the task I am trying to achieve easier (a quick visual plot of survey results comparing three visualisation systems). I appreciate that might be tricky to suggest without seeing the original data shape, and might not help in any case. However, I explicitly welcome that frame challenge if relevant! :) (I used an approach based on [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62883806/4647265) FWIW)

Comment: I'm unsure what's going on at first glance, maybe open an issue in the repo if you can reproduce with one of the gallery examples. As a workaround, you can use the Offset channels for grouped charts, I found this more convenient in general, e.g. https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html

Comment: Thanks for weighing in on another Altair query @joelostblom! I can indeed repro using an example dataset, adding `sort` to the `alt.Column` specification results in no sort. I'll open an issue ([done](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3386))  and I'll try out offset :)

Comment: @joelostblom -- your suggestion of using xOffset works, since that swapped things around to where the `sort` happens to the X axis. If you would like to post it as an answer -- no obligation of course, I can do so if you would prefer -- I'll happily furnish you with the code and screenshot! :)

Comment: It fits in a comment with plenty to spare! Image: https://i.imgur.com/NkrMtNt.png , code: `alt.Chart(d1).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('mean(value):Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1,5]),),
    alt.X('attribute:N',
          axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-0, title=None,),
          sort=["easy to use", "easy to understand", "complete", "representative", 
              "visually appealing", "b&l useful", "rating"],
         ),
    alt.XOffset('system:N'),
    color='system:N',
    tooltip=['mean(value)', 'attribute', 'system', 'count()'],
    
)`

Comment: Happy to hear it's working! I'm happy for you to post an answer if you want. I'm leaving the link to the follow up issue here with link to VL bug https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3386

Comment: Thanks again, I've compiled the info from the discussions across here and GitHub into an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround: use `xOffset` for a visually-similar result

Instead of using a Column grouping, it is possible to use [xOffset](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.XOffset.html#altair.XOffset) (one of [several channels](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encodings/channels.html) available in Altair charts) to achieve a similar outcome.

```py
alt.Chart(d1).mark_bar().encode(
     alt.Y('mean(value):Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1,5]),),
     alt.X('attribute:N',
           axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-0, title=None,),
           sort=["easy to use", "easy to understand", "complete", "representative",
                "visually appealing", "b&l useful", "rating"],
          ),
     alt.XOffset('system:N'),
     color='system:N',
     tooltip=['mean(value)', 'attribute', 'system', 'count()'],
)
```

The `sort` parameter is moved to the [x-axis](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.X.html#altair.X), where it produces the correct result- a custom sort order based on the supplied list.

[image: xoffset ordering]

It is also possible to [reorder the data itself](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3386#issuecomment-2020634691) and let the sort be based on source data order.

#### Why a workaround?

As discussed on the [related issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3386), there is a bug in Vega-Lite, which Atair is a python wrapper for. Quoting Joel Ostblom from there:

> After some exploring, it seems to be an issue with aggregating and sorting facets at the same time. I had no idea this was an existing bug, but it has been reported in VL already here [vega/vega-lite#5366](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5366); you might be able to ask for workaround there and thumbs up that issue.

The [existing bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5366) notes that Vega-Lite does not produce the correct ordering when supplied a custom order.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the aggregation in a transform does work. Example using different data:

```
import altair as alt  
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Column('site:N',
               sort=["Waseca", "Morris", "University Farm", 
                     "Grand Rapids", "Crookston", "Duluth"]
              ),
    x='year:O',
    color='year:N',
)

chart1 = base.encode(y=alt.Y('sum(yield):Q'))
chart2 = base.transform_aggregate(y2="sum(yield)",groupby=['site', 'year']).encode(y=alt.Y('y2:Q'))

chart1 | chart2
```

[image]